# Spherical interpolation in Matlab from Cartesian Grid

Tags: matlab, interpolation, cartesian-coordinates, spherical-coordinate

I have a 3D image. I need to take spherical wave decomposition of this image hence I need to convert my 3d image in the cartesian grid to spherical coordinates.

If below is too long to read, gist of what I want is that I want to a mapping that will interpolate the spherical coordinates such that, especially around my origin I don't have a lot of missing information.

First, I do the spherical conversion.

```
    [ydim,xdim,zdim] = size(myimg);

    [x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:xdim, 1:ydim, 1:zdim);
    x = x - median(x(:)); y = y - median(y(:)); z = z - median(z(:)); 
    [phis, thetas, rs] = cart2sph(x,y,z);
```

From here I am stuck. How can I use my phis and thetas and r's to do interpolation along an arc (I just assume it would be an arc since it's a sphere).

I actually searched about this a bit and brought together this code for interpolation but I can't verify it works. Mainly because most of it is copied and modified from a similar problem.

```
function [theta0,phi0,rho0] = my_interp(X, Y, Z, nTheta0, nPhi0)
% forget about spherical, let's just interpolate in cartesian then convert 
% to spherical. 
[theta, phi, V] = cart2sph(X, Y, Z);

% X,Y,Z are meshgrid output from above code snippet.
P = [2 1 3];
X = permute(X, P);
Y = permute(Y, P);
Z = permute(Z, P);
V = permute(V, P);

% create a cartesian interpolant, and we'll use it in spherical.
F = griddedInterpolant(X,Y,Z,V);

% prepare grid for meshing (we'll mesh xyz data, not theta,phi)
theta0 = linspace(-pi, pi, nTheta0);
phi0   = linspace(-pi/2, pi/2, nPhi0);
[theta0, phi0] = meshgrid(theta0, phi0);

[x_,y_,z_] = sph2cart(theta0, phi0, 1 ); % !! here is why I get confused. my 
% radius on the sphere is not just 1, I have changing radius. Am I really     
% missing the key insight here? On the other hand, I don't know how to      
% account for all the r's on the image anyways so I can't change this.
rho0 = F(x_,y_,z_);

theta0 = repmat(theta0, 1, 1, size(X, 3));
phi0 = repmat(phi0, 1, 1, size(X, 3));
rho0 = repmat(rho0, 1, 1, size(X, 3));
end
```

Comment: Would SLERP do the right stuff for you? It’s based on quaternions, which is basically a rotation representation like imaginary numbers for a 3D rotation.

Comment: @Dorian , how would I apply SLERP here? I thought about it but couldn't figure it out. Matlab has quatinterp but how do I select my 2 vectors?

Comment: you would have to create 2 quaternions (not vectors), that would define your initial rotation and your stop rotation. It's not super intuitive though.
Basically, you would need to vary all imaginary components with linspace and then convert those quats to whatever you want to (but please don't use Euler angles..)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a grid of cartedian coordinates and converting those to spherical, you want to create a grid of spherical coordinates, convert those to cartesian, then use `interp3` to find the image values at those coordinates.

Spherical coordinate grid could be something like `meshgrid(0:maxR,0:phiStep:2*pi,0:thetaStep:pi)`.

Comment: I have a 50x50x2 image. But R goes up to 25 (maxR). Then when I do what you say with meshgrid(linspace(0,2*pi,180),linspace(0,pi,90),linspace(0,maxR,100)), I get a huge array. My problem is the Z dimension of these (it's 100). But I don't think making 100 to 2 is going to solve it. Is this the nature of interpolation? My main issue was only with how points didn't distribute nicely on the origin.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question then. If you have a 50x50x2 image you don't have a whole lot of a 3rd dimension, I'm not sure what kind of 3D information you could get out of there. And what do you mean by "points didn't distribute nicely on the origin"? In spherical coordinates, if you sample densely enough for large r, you will oversample for small r. The origin is always awkward: for r=0, you get a constant value for all phi and theta (redundant information). There's no solution for that.

Comment: simply put, I have f(r,theta,phi) for Cartesian voxels (ie image pixel intensities at 3D image). These are obviously discrete, how can I get an interpolant that would give me f(r,theta',phi') for arbitrary theta' and phi' ? I have an integral that goes to 0 to 2pi and 0 to pi for  theta and phi which involves f(r,theta,phi) and I need to use this interpolant for this integration.